# Перенос строки таблицы в калькуляторе

Tags: html

Будьте добры, подскажите как в калькуляторе сделать из одной строки две строки? пробовал через tr, не работает. Мне необходимо ячейки друг над другом сделать.
[image: Скрин]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>` - тэг начала новой строки в таблице
`<br>` - тег переноса строки
`<hr>` - линия и перенос строки

```html
    <table border =1 >
      <tr>                                         <!-- //новая строка -->
        <td>Первая колонка первая строка</td>      <!-- //первая колонка -->
        <td>Вторая колонка первая строка</td>      <!-- //вторая колонка в первой строке -->
      </tr>                                        <!-- //закончить первую строку -->
      <tr>                                         <!-- //начать вторую строку.... -->
        <td>Первая колонка вторая строка</td>      <!-- //первая колонка во второй строке -->
        <td>Вторая колонка вторая строка<br>текст на новой строке в старой колонке</td>      <!-- //вторая колонка во второй строке -->
      </tr>                                        <!-- //закончить вторую строку -->

      <tr>                                         <!-- //начать третью строку.... -->
        <td colspan=2>Единственная колонка третья строка</td>      <!-- //первая колонка во второй строке -->
      </tr>                                        <!-- //закончить третью строку -->

<!-- ................ -->
    </table>                                       <!-- //закончить таблицу -->
```

Comment: Я это знаю.) Я ведь написал, что не работает там  "tr". Это калькулятор и мне надо перенести 2 ячейки наверх.

Comment: Что именно не работает в указанном мной коде?(добавил пример его работы)

Comment: Добавил скрин, где не работает.

Comment: Ваш код работать не может, количество столбцов должно быть идентично для всех строк. Для объединения столбцов используйте свойство `colspan` пример: `<td colspan=4></td>` Обновил пример

Comment: Не работало по причине отсутствия после "tr" знака "\". )) Перенос на другую строку получился, а вот алгоритм расчета пропал. Пытаюсь понять где зарыта...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <hr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

hr вам в помощь или любой другой блок с шириной на всю длину